# ERROR AL COMPILAR EN ARDUINO

Tags: arduino, almacenamiento

AL COMPILAR UN PROGRAMA EN ARDUINO ME SALE ESTO

```
El Sketch usa 1728 bytes (0%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 253952 bytes.
```

AYUDA POR FAVOR

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Coloca tu código para entender el motivo del error. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que eres nuevo en Arduino, no te preocupes, el mensaje que ves no es un error, es solo un dialogo de información y se refiere al espacio de almacenamiento que tu código esta ocupando.
[image: Ejemplo de un mensaje normal]

Ahora, la siguiente imagen muestra un error, sale una barra naranja indicándote el error.
[image: Ejemplo de un mensaje de error]